# jQuery panels - close one when opening another

Tags: jquery, slider, panel

I have two slide panel in the same page. Need that, when one is open and the and user clicks on the other one, that makes, at the same time, close the first one when opening the second. Now they are overlapping...

Can you help me, please? thanks

This is what i have on the page:

I have two slide panel in the same page. Need that, when one is open and the and user clicks on the other one, that makes, at the same time, close the first one when opening the second. Now they are overlapping...

Can you help me, please? thanks

This is what i have on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle('fast');
  $("#panel2").slideToggle("fast");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-slide2").click(function(){
  $("#panel2").slideUp('fast');
  $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

mybe this could help you

http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/m4BTd/

```
<div class="accordionButton">111111</div>
<div class="accordionContent">0000000</div>
<div class="accordionButton">222222</div>
<div class="accordionContent">99999999</div>
<div class="accordionButton">33333333</div>
<div class="accordionContent">88888888</div>
​

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
            $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('slow');  
            if(!$(this).next().is(':visible')){
            $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
            }
        });
        $("div.accordionContent").hide();


    });​
```

Comment: Thanks but i must try to keep it as much as possible in names as it is already, i already have class and css working fine, except that problem...

Comment: I really neded to change something only on this part to make that happens:

    $(document).ready(function(){
 
     $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
      $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
     });
 
  
    });
    </script>
 
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
 
     $(".btn-slide2").click(function(){
      $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
      $(this).toggleClass("active2"); return false;
     });
 
  
    });

Comment: I put the full page in this link, could you take a look at the source code?

Like I said, have to change something in the javascript but keeping the div and class names i already have working.

http://supra5.com/r2pro/slidePanel/ipec2.html